# readyState = 4 three times in the row. Ajax - caused by alert

Tags: javascript, ajax, stack

I have a strange situation.

Try double clicking on "Insane" [on this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/B9a5G/1/). You will notice that `onreadystatechange` is called 3 times. All these times with `readyState = 4`. For me, this is insane.

But the zinger is that when I remove the `alert(added)` from the double click event listener function as shown [in this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/B9a5G/3/), then everything is OK.

Is there somebody who can explain to me what happened ? It is very strange for me.Thanks in advance. :)

Comment: works fine if you use console.log in place of alert

Comment: May I suggest the usage of a js library such as jQuery or Dojo to help you out?  It takes away many issues such as this, and will also provide support for IE

Comment: @wirey That's because `console.log` doesn't pause the JavaScript execution thread.

Comment: @Justanotherdunce (1)No it doesn't, (2)What if he doesn't need IE6- support? (3)You don't need a full-fledged library for one functionality.

Comment: @Zirak they provides a clear method of creating ajax calls and dom manipulation.

Comment: @Justanotherdunce And the native XHR isn't clear? And he doesn't do DOM manipulation. YAGNI.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is happening because your XMLHttpRequest is set to execute asynchronously **and** your `alert('added')` halts the JavaScript execution thread before XMLHttpRequest begins to invoke `onreadystatechange`. By the time you close the alert, the XMLHttpRequest has already completed and the four calls to `onreadystatechange` are sitting in the stack, pending execution.

Thus, because your XMLHttpRequest has already completed, `.readyState` and `.status` are already equal to `4` and `200` respectively. So with each `.onreadystatechange` call, your `if` statements evaluate true.

If you change the XMLHttpRequest to execute synchronously (or if you place `alert('added')` before invoking AJAX), then you get the number of alerts you would expect:

http://jsfiddle.net/B9a5G/6/

More on JavaScript events, timing and single-threaded processing:

http://javascript.info/tutorial/events-and-timing-depth

Answer (score 0):

Simplest way is to write your alert after checking readyState
like this
    function myCallback() {
        if (g_xmlHttpRequest.readyState != 4)
            return;
        alert("myCallback");
         // add some code 
    }